# I am trying to learn flutter and firbase. I have followed the instructions given but am still getting this error

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0:.
> Required by:
> project :
> this is my project build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0'
        
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
       
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

this is my app build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {
    namespace "com.example.learndart"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.learndart"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
   implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.6.0"))
}
```

I have tired changing syntax reinstalling firebase looked through some tutorials to figure out what I have been doing wrong. Tell me what I did wrong and how to fixit with all the steps as I am still new to this.

Comment: Have you downloaded the google.services from firebase website?

Comment: yes, I have downloaded the google.services from firebase website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have already downloaded the google-services.json file and imported it, notice the following line in the error message

`com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0` in your project level build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0'
        
  }
```

change `com.google.gms.google-services:4.4.0` to `com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0` like so

```
 dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
        
  }
```

**Notice the change of '.' to ':' after gms.**

When you have **apply** preceeding, you should use `'com.google.gms.google...'` but when **classpath** is preceeding, you should use `'com.google.gms:google...'`

Clean and rebuild application.

Comment: Awesome! If this particular solution is what you used, you could accept it as the answer to make searching easier.